# Kernel of homomorphism from $\mathbb (Q,+)$ to finite group G

Tags: group-theory

If $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to a finite group $G$, the prove that $$\phi(q) = e_g\forall q\in\mathbb Q \text{ where } e_g \text{ is identity}$$

Comment: @Einer I was trying to use the fact that all elements of $G$ have finite order, but that seemed like a dead end,

Comment: But this idea will work. Which elements of $(\mathbb Q,+)$ do have finite order?

Comment: @Einer $0$, the identity

Comment: So, if $\phi(x) \neq e_g$, what about $\phi(\frac x 2), \phi(\frac x 4), \ldots$? edit: I have to say that my previous question might have been misleading. Sorry about that, but now we are back on track.

Comment: $\phi(x)=\phi(\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x}{n}+\cdots+\frac{x}{n})\implies \phi(x)=\left(\phi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right)^n$ and $\phi(\frac{x}{n})\neq e_g$

Comment: And now, what about the order of $\phi(\frac x 2), \phi(\frac x 4), \ldots$?

Comment: @Einer order of $\phi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ would be $n$ times order of x

Comment: Right and this completes the proof, since $G$ has only finitely many elements, so that only finitely many, different orders can occur.

Comment: @Einer oh wow, nice one. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome (:

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know $\mathbb Q$ is a [divisible group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group). It is a well know result that says: `Every quotient of a divisible group is also divisible`. A divisible group *cannot* be finite so if we accept that such homomorphism exists then $|\mathbb Q/\text{ker}(\phi)|<\infty$ which is a contradiction unless...